# problem: subdivision surface modifier fails on non-convex faces

Tags: subdivision-surface

Is it a known issue (in blender 3.4.1), that subdivision surface modifier fails on non-convex geometries? It results in invalid geometries.

Look at the example of a cube cut out from a cube.
It works, if I first triangulate faces. However I would like to leave the n-gons as far as possible as they are convenient in other circumstances.

Is there a possibility to only triangulate those faces that are not already convex?

regards
~eichhofener

non-convex n-gon on top:
[image: cube cut out from a cube: the topmost frame ist not convex]

result from subdivision-surface:
[image]

Comment: What does your geometry look like in Edit mode before adding the modifier? - If I simply use Ctrl-R to loop cut across the cube and extrude one of the cut faces it works correctly.

Comment: @John Eason:
It is really just an n-gon with 6 vertices in xy-plane extruded in z-direction.
I uploaded an example: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=YvZZjMw5" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/YvZZjMw5/)

Your approach works, because you end up with the top and the bottom consisting of 3 faces each. Hence all the faces are convex.

Comment: Meanwhile I have read in other posts that geometry with n-gons is considered as "poor". And the algorithm was failing because of that.
So the problem is known apparently. However it is still a bug, isn't it? The algorithm should at least report about the issue in the generated mesh, imho.

Comment: This is not a bug. This is the way it works, no more... why do you want or need to keep ngons?

Comment: @eichhofener Why should the algorithm report about it? Just because it is not working well with n-gons, it does not throw an error - because it can do something with the geometry, it's just not good. And Blender does not know if you probably do not care about the result...

Comment: @lemon, @ Gordon Brinkmann: I do not want to troll around and you certainly know more about blender and the implicit contracts its algorithms come with. But before calling the modifier I have valid geometry and after calling it I have invalid geometry. Furthermore the modifier apparently is about subdivision of surfaces and it does not do so in the example but generates surfaces where there were none before. That's why I was thinking, it could be called a bug. But I got a way around it and that is all I wanted. Thank you (I learned a lot from both of your answers in my other question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question if there is an option to only triangulate faces that are not already convex: it is not necessary to triangulate them, making them quads is sufficient for your case - and yes, there is an option:

In *Edit Mode*, go to the *Mesh* menu and choose *Clean Up* > *Split Concave Faces*:

[image: split concave faces]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for asking too many questions. I've just started to use blender and at the beginning of the learning curve, the options are overwhelming.